# как можно сгенерировать и заменить значения строк column -> number_phones в PostgreSQL рандомными, НО уникальными целочисленными значениями bigint?

Tags: postgresql, psql

может кто то сможет подсказать, как можно решить данную задачу, я еще новичок и пока не могу разобраться.
дана таблица users, столбец (колонка) phone_number (NOT NULL), в ней нужно скрыть конфиденциальные данные клиентов, заменив другими в каком нибудь целочисленном диапазоне с аналогичным количеством символов. в ней более 11 000 строк.
пробовал сделать что то вроде этого:
`UPDATE users SET phone_number  = floor(random() * (71119991234-71110001234) + 71110001234)::bigint;`
но это не гарантирует уникальность генерируемых данных.
соответственно получаю ошибку:
`ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_phone_number_unique"`

что я еще могу использовать для данной задачи?

Comment: Нагенерируй уникальных случайных номеров с запасом во временную таблицу, а потом обновляй.

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
with generated_number as (
   select id, 71110001234 + row_number over() number
   from users
)
update users
set phone_number = number
from generated_number g 
where g.id = users.id
```